# Teradata sample database

Tags: teradata

I have installed vmware player and added the disk file to it. Teradata studio is already installed in it. Now, I want create a database of good size to perform bulk load types in Teradata.

Where can I get the sample database?

Comment: I don't think anyone actually understood his question. Does Teradata have sample data that can be loaded. Something like the Wide World Imports database provided by Microsoft for SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are asking about the software part to create an instance of Teradata database. If you have VMware downloaded from Teradata for evaluation purpose, it is already installed and configured. You just have to connect with your Studio.

If you are trying to create a virtual environment on your own, then you need to download the Teradata software and install in machine which will create a database. After installing the software you can configure and connect with Studio.

Comment: Is it fine now?

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow. I will improve my editing skills. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Teradata Express comes with toy data (Samples database) but only up to version 14. From version 15 it is (oddly) removed.

Answer (score 0):

Your VM-Ware is fully configured. Sart your TD-Studio and connect to it.

From VM-Ware's TD-Studio it is TDPID: localhost od 127.0.0.1  User dbc  pass dbc

Answer (score 0):

There are no more sample databases in Teradata Express, but I published several data sets on [GitHub](https://github.com/dnoeth), see the blog on [Teradata Community](https://community.teradata.com/t5/Blog/Demo-databases-for-download/ba-p/85684)